# aiortc server example does not display video on server

Tags: webrtc, aiortc

I want to test `https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/tree/master/examples/server` on remote server, so I installed everything on `digital ocean` cloud. Now, after running `python server.py` the web page is displayed as expected, but no audio or video is working. Whats going wrong?

The JS console gives the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined
    at start (client.js:169)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):78)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/leon-ai/leon/issues/97).

> Chrome disables features such as `getUserMedia` when it comes from an
>   unsecured origin. `http://localhost` is considered as a secure origin by
>   default, however if you use an origin that does not have an SSL/TLS
>   certificate then Chrome will consider the origin as unsecured and
>   disable `getUserMedia`.
>
> What you can do is:
>
> 1. Setup an SSL/TLS certificate.
> 2. Or go to `chrome://flags`, search for the
>      flag `unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`, enter the origin you
>      want to treat as secure such as `http://{YOUR HOST IP}:1337`, enable the
>      feature and relaunch the browser. Let me know if that works.